# Overwrite array with array

Tags: c++

I have an array which is called array[9][7]. Now I want to start an empty array (How do I do this?) and overwrite this array with the content of the array[9][7].

So I want, in a particular case, to copy the array [9][7] into a new array. How do I manage this?

I tried:

```
newarray[];
array[9][7] = ....

newarray[] = array[9][7];
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: What is an *empty* array?  Arrays are never empty.  The contain uninitialized values when created (or they can be zero filled).

Comment: Use `memcpy` and the `new[]` operator

Comment: Your *new* array must have the same dimensions as the other array.  See `std::copy`.

Comment: I'd go for one dimensional vector, instead of trying to explain to you, how C-arrays really works

Comment: Since you are on C++, please use its features. Use `std::vector`. They are copy-assignable and you wouldn't have this problem with them.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector`. They both provide assignment operators out of the box.

Comment: arrays are for compile time constant length containers, to copy you know the length at compile time so hard code the other with the same lengths. copy using std::copy in a for loop over the first part, or for c-style use a nested for loop with fixed lengths

Comment: Your new array also needs to be `[9][7]` and then you can `memcpy()` the old one to the new one.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is extremely frustrating to hear. Doesn't work how? Did it produce an error? Did it do something unexpected? Be more specific.

Comment: If `array[9][7]` itself is an array then *what is the type of `array`*?

Comment: @tadman it doesn't work in the same way they didn't work in any way to study this topic before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable.

You can copy the elements of one array into another. There is a standard algorithm for copying elements:

```
std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), std::begin(dest));
```

However, this algorithm requires for the elements to be assignable. But the elements of your array are arrays and therefore not assignable.

You could use the following instead:

```
int array[9][7] = ...;
int newarray[9][7];

constexpr auto count = std::size(array) * std::size(array[0]);
std::copy(array[0], array[0] + count, newarray[0]);
```

This relies on the assumption that iterating across sub-array borders is well-defined, which is arguably not guaranteed by the standard (there are differing interpretations of the standard).

If you take the stand that the above is undefined, you can use `std::memcpy` instead, but keep in mind that it requires the elements to be trivially copyable:

```
std::memcpy(newarray, array, sizeof array);
```

---

Another approach is to wrap the array inside a class. The compiler generates implicit special member functions for classes, and they are both copy constructible and copy assignable. Here is an expample using copy assignment:

```
struct Wrapper {
    int arr[9][7];
};

Wrapper array = ...;
Wrapper newarray;
newarray = array;
```

You don't necessarily need to write the wrapper yourself. The standard library provides you with a template for such wrapper: `std::array`. Here is an example using copy construction and type deduction:

```
std::array<9, std::array<7, int>> array = ...;
auto newarray = array; // has same type
```